# Exclude post category in a blog page

Tags: posts, categories, blog, exclude

I have two links in

- "news" where all the news posts goes
- "blog" where the rest goes

just wanted to exclude the category "news" in the blog page

I use the code

```
$news = new WP_query ('category_name =-news')
```

and it is not working

Essentially, I want tell wordpress, I want all the posts to go into the "blog" page but not in the post that is categorize as "news"

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php file, use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and swap out the -1 in the following code with the category I.D you want to exclude from your posts page.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameters `cat` or `category__not_in`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-1234' );
```

The minus means to exclude, the ID is used.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 1234 ) ) );
```

Uses the ID too.

Use [`get_cat_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) to get the ID by name or [`get_category_by_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) to do it by slug, the latter returns an object though.